# How to force a re-install from deb repository after local package screw-up?

Tags: debian, package-management, repository

I mistakenly screwed up my tex-live installation on lenny, by trying to locally install some squeeze packages.

I've got a list of packages that are in state 'pU', and I'd like to replace them all by the a clean known to be working repository version.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
apt-get --reinstall install mypackage
```

Option `--reinstall` will tell apt-get to install the given package, even if it believes that the same version is already installed.