# Restoring /etc/init.d/apache2 on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

In my web-server configuration troubleshooting I went through a process of uninstalling apache2 and reinstalling it. I accidentally removed the file `/etc/init.d/apache2` which is responsible for starting and stopping the apache service.

I've tried reinstalling the `apache2.2-common` package which is supposed to place the file, but it is still not present.

How can I do a complete reinstall of Apache? The standard `apt-get remove` and `apt-get install` doesn't give me that file back.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force a re-install from deb repository after local package screw-up?](http://serverfault.com/questions/188622/how-to-force-a-re-install-from-deb-repository-after-local-package-screw-up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get -o DPkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" --reinstall install apache2.2-common
```

This will let you replace config file with out purging package.
To remove package use

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2.2-common
```

and then install apache the normal way:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Yes, it's back!!! :D

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to delete the package first. Just reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2.2-common
```

Comment: Does not fix my problem, but thanks.

Comment: It would if I put in the right package name. :)

Comment: Read this line of my question: `"I've tried reinstalling the apache2.2-common package which is supposed to place the file, but it is still not present."` That did not solve the problem.